# unicode-math/expl3 error: Support package l3kernel too old

Tags: errors, expl3, unicode-math

Consider the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

When this code is run with `lualatex`, it aborts with the following error message:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 26, version
               `2018/02/21' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2017/12/16 L3 programming layer (loader) '
               is available.


! Package xparse Error: Support package l3kernel too old.

See the xparse package documentation for explanation.
```

If the 2nd line (`\usepackage{unicode-math}`) is deleted, `lualatex` compiles the file successfully.

Adding the command `\listfiles` at the beginning of the file and recompiling, the lines starting with `Package:` inside the log file are:

```
Package: expl3 2017/12/16 L3 programming layer (loader) 
Package: unicode-math 2018/02/02 vv0.8l Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

My TeX Live Utility does not list any updates to these two packages.

Comment: Update again and you'll be again in sync.

Comment: @egreg: I tried, but my TeX Live Utility lists no packages in the updatable package list.

Comment: Wait till tomorrow, possibly the mirror you use hasn't been updated yet. In the meantime, downgrade `l3packages` to the backup. See http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-February/041083.html

Comment: @egreg: I've just updated, and the problem has indeed resolved. Thanks.